# C# - How to sort a list of strings using last character by ignoring special character if any at the end

Tags: c#, string, sorting, generic-list

Below is the logic that i tried to implement and able to sort it but need to figure out to ignore special characters in it

My Logic:

- Reversed string in a list
- Sorted in ascending order
- Again reversed back sorted strings &
- Finally returned as a string by joining with ~ delimiter.

  ```
      List<String> inputLst= new List<String>() { "Bananas!", "Cherry2",
      "Mango","Apples", "Grape$", "Guava" };

      List<String> sortList = new List<String>();
      List<String> outputList = new List<String>();

      foreach (String str in inputLst)
      {
          sortList.Add(new String(str.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray()));
      }
      sortList.Sort();

      foreach (String str in sortList)
      {
          outputList.Add(new String(str.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray()));
      }
      Return String.Join("~", outputList);
  ```

Output i got is `Bananas!~Grape$~Cherry2~Guava~Mango~Apples`

Expected output should be `Guava~Grape$~Mango~Bananas!~Apples~Cherry2`

Could anyone please suggest me optimized solution to sort a list by last character by ignoring special characters? Here i used 2 lists for string reversals, can it be done in more efficient way?
Note: without using LINQ pls.

Comment: why don't you want to write your custom comparator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a bit of LINQ and Regex, this can be achieved relatively simply:

```
var inputList = new List<string>() { "Bananas!", "Cherry2", "Mango","Apples", "Grape$", "Guava" };

var outputList = inputList.OrderBy(s => new string(Regex.Replace(s, "[^a-zA-Z]", "")
                                                        .Reverse()
                                                        .ToArray()))
                          .ToList();

var output = String.Join("~", outputList);
```

---

**EDIT:** Non-LINQ approach:

```
var inputList = new List<string>() { "Bananas!", "Cherry2", "Mango", "Apples", "Grape$", "Guava" };

inputList.Sort(new ReverseStringComparer());

var output = String.Join("~", inputList);
```

ReverseStringComparer:

```
class ReverseStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        string a = new string(Regex.Replace(x, "[^a-zA-Z]", "").Reverse().ToArray());
        string b = new string(Regex.Replace(y, "[^a-zA-Z]", "").Reverse().ToArray());
        return a.CompareTo(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it works fine. I was hoping to have a solution without using LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Solution without regex:

```
string foo()
{
    List<String> inputLst= new List<String>() { "Bananas!", "Cherry2", "Mango","Apples", "Grape$", "Guava" };

    inputLst.Sort((l, r) => new string(l.Reverse().SkipWhile( x => !char.IsLetter(x) ).ToArray()).CompareTo( new string(r.Reverse().SkipWhile(x => !char.IsLetter(x)).ToArray()) ) );

    return String.Join("~", inputLst);
}
```

To skip all non letter chars (and not only at the beginning of string) as suggested in comment, just use `Where` instead of `SkipWhile` like this:

```
string bar()
{
    List<String> inputLst= new List<String>() { "Bananas!", "Cherry2", "Mango","Apples", "Grape$", "Guava" };

    inputLst.Sort((l, r) => new string(l.Reverse().Where( x => char.IsLetter(x) ).ToArray()).CompareTo( new string(r.Reverse().Where(x => char.IsLetter(x)).ToArray()) ) );

    return String.Join("~", inputLst);
}
```

Notice `Where` has invers logic (`char.IsLetter(x)`) compare to `SkipWhile` (`!char.IsLetter(x)`).

Comment: This won't work if there are special characters in the middle of the string. For example, "b1a" will appear before "aaa", but ignoring the number, should come after. ("aaa" vs "ab")

Comment: @Abion47 nothing it's just solution without regex for some who don't want or can't use it. It's complementary to your solution as it's use different mechanisms of `List` and it's done in place. Also question title clearly suggests that OP want only to remove special chars at the end and not in the middle or beginning of string.

Answer (score -1):

Find the last symbol being the letter and sort by it.

```
var inputList = new List<string>() {
    "Bananas!", "Cherry2", "Mango","Apples", "Grape$", "Guava" };

var outputList = inputList.OrderBy(s => s.Last(c => char.IsLetter(c)));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("~", outputList));
```

Reverse is not needed.

Comment: Again, `Last()` won't work as a sorting mechanism if multiple words have a common last character.

Comment: @Abion47 - `Last(c => char.IsLetter(c))` in word `a&b` found `b`, not `a`. So, it works as it should.

Comment: In a list `"az", "dz", "cz", "bz"`, the elements will either be unchanged or unpredictably sorted (depending on the implementation of the sorting algorithm) because only the `'z'` in each of them is considered.

Comment: @Abion47 - OP wants sort "_using last character_". So the condition is met.

Comment: He also says that the desired output from the example should be "Bananas!" before "Apples", which is something that cannot be guaranteed if only comparing against the last character.